# What happens to an enchanted non magic bonded/pact weapon while in "hammer space"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

What happens to an enchanted weapon in a warlock's/Eldritch Knight's dimensional pocket? Say you cast Magic Weapon on a non magic bonded/pact weapon, it becomes a +1 weapon up to an hour. You then have a 5 to 10 minute combat encounter leaving some 50 minutes left remaining on the enchanted weapon. You then pop said weapon into the warlock's/Eldritch Knight's dimension pocket.

Now, until whenever the next combat encounter happens (could be hours, days, weeks if you're lucky), will the weapon still be enchanted when re-summoning it. Is the dimensional space the bonded/pact weapon is stored in, keep it in a temporal stasis where once it's placed there enchantment and all effects , it remain that way till it is re-summoned.

> Magic Weapon
>
> Transmutation
>
> Level: 2
>
> Casting time: 1 Bonus Action
>
> Range: Touch
>
> Components: V, S
> Duration: Concentration, up to 1 hour
>
> You touch a nonmagical weapon. Until the spell ends, that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls.
>
> At higher levels:
> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 4th level or higher, the bonus increases to +2.
> When you use a spell slot of 6th level or higher, the bonus increases to +3.

Page: 257 Players Handbook

Answer (score 16):

### It stops being magical because you (probably) stop concentrating on it.

Note that the spell requires that you concentrate on it for it to be active. If a combat encounter ends and you stop concentrating on it, the weapon stops being magical. You also cannot concentrate on the spell past the 1 hour limit, so the spell will be inactive when you re-summon it for a later fight.

It's possible for a character to continue concentrating on the spell at the end of an encounter. Then, if they begin a new combat encounter before the time is up and they haven't stopped concentrating, they could re-summon their weapon and the spell would still be active.

### Extradimensional spaces generally don't freeze time.

Other instances of extradimensional spaces refer to the passage of time as if it progressed normally. For example, the Portable Hole states

> A breathing creature within a closed portable hole can survive for up to 10 minutes, after which time it begins to suffocate.

Which does not draw a distinction between the passage of time inside and outside the space. Given that the class features don't address this, I think it's a safe bet that the extradimensional space for pact weapons don't freeze time either.

Answer (score 7):

Well, firstly, the Eldritch Knight is sort of irrelevant here. They have no "dimensional pocket" ability, merely the ability to teleport a weapon into their hand.

Secondly, you can't cast *Magic Weapon* on a pact weapon. *Magic Weapon* requires a nonmagical weapon, which a pact weapon isn't:

> This
>   weapon
>   counts
>   as
>   magical
>   for
>   the
>   purpose
>   of
>   overcoming
>   resistance
>   and
>   immunity
>   to
>   nonmagical
>   attacks
>   and
>   damage.

Thirdly, you can't "pop said weapon into the warlock's/Eldritch Knight's dimension pocket". When you use Pact of the Blade, you *create* a weapon, not summon it from a dimensional pocket:

> You
>   can
>   use
>   your
>   action
>   to
>   create
>   a
>   pact
>   weapon
>   in
>   your
>   empty
>   hand.
>   You
>   can
>   choose
>   the
>   form
>   that
>   this
>   melee
>   weapon
>   takes
>   each
>   time
>   you
>   create
>   it.

The ability to shunt a weapon into an extradimensional space is only for magical weapons that you use a ritual to make your pact weapon.

The only way this could *possibly* work would be if you took an ordinary weapon, cast *Magic Weapon* on it, and *then* performed the ritual to make it your pact weapon. But the ritual takes an hour, so you would need to use Extended Spell to have enough time. If you did do this, theoretically you could have a weapon stored with *Magic Weapon* cast on it. Once that's the case, the problems outlined in [@Icyfire's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/98286/15469) come into play, with the added issue of your pact weapon no longer being a valid choice for a pact weapon. What happens at that point is up to your DM, but it's probably not good news for your plan.

Comment: Heh, I totally forgot that a pact weapon isn't a valid target for Magic Weapon.

Comment: @Icyfire Hey, I'm glad you did - it saved me having to write stuff about extradimensional spaces!

Comment: I disagree: "for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage" seems to have no bearing on the spell; what am I missing?

Comment: @Chemus I suspected I'd get some questions about that. It's a temporary creation of magic, that ceases to exist when the warlock gets bored of it. Honestly, I think they only specified that to prevent arguments over whether its intrinsically magical nature counted for overcoming resistances. Also, there is, as far as anyone can tell, no distinction between "magical" and "counts as magical for resistances".

Comment: Too bad that they didn't define 'Magical weapon' as any weapon enhanced, produced or created by magic, then. It'd be really simple. Or even just say 'this is a magic weapon' when it's true. Ah well, carry on then, nothing to see here.

Comment: "Counts as magical for the purposes of..." means it doesn't count as magical for any other purpose. If it were a magic weapon, they'd call it a magic weapon. It would've been much simpler to read and write. Note that Ki-Empowered Strikes work the same way. Ki abilities aren't magical unless they explicitly say so ([1](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/702205711011328000), [2](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/530137985954492416)).