# Are magic weapons and weapons considered magic for the purpose of overcoming resistances different?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, magic

After reading [an interesting comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98285/what-happens-to-an-enchanted-non-magic-bonded-pact-weapon-while-in-hammer-space#comment231056_98287) in another question, I realized there are some rare cases when the difference between a magic weapon and a weapon considered magical for the purposes of overcoming resistances (WCMFTPOOR) actually becomes mechanically relevant.

An example is the Magic Weapon spell, which explicitly requires nonmagical weapons in its casting. Another is the Animate Objects spell. A third one is the Elemental Weapon spell. Likely, there are other effects that require nonmagical weapons.

Meanwhile, there are effects that create a WCMFTPOOR. One example is the Warlock's Pact of the Blade.

So, as the title states: are magic weapons different from WCMFTPOOR?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking specifically whether a WCMFTPOOR can be a target for spells like Magic Weapon or Elemental Weapon and other effects that require a non-magical weapon as the target?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I am only asking if they are different. That I mentioned the spells and the EK's class feature are only there to support the question, as a first glance look may garner an "of course not" or "of course they are" and generate down votes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The rules say precisely what they mean

The phrase "...considered magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage" means precisely that, nothing more and nothing less. If the weapon were magical, the text would say so. If it were magical for any other purposes, the text would say so (and it would've been far simpler to state it that way).

Granted, there are places where the rules rely on the everyday English and some ambiguity sneaks in, but this isn't one of those cases.

Here's an example of a related rule that's defined in a similarly pedantic way: immunity or resistance to "bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks not made with silvered weapons." If you hit a werewolf with a torch, it'll take fire damage; swinging the torch was a nonmagical attack, but it didn't deal bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage. If you push a werewolf off a cliff, it takes falling damage; falling isn't an attack. And of course if you attack a werewolf with a nonmagical silvered weapon, it takes damage.

The text behind the rule is a mouthful, but it's written that way because the authors want it to work that way ([1](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/525717882177454081), [2](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/525770675345035264), [3](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/526084242283843584)). They could've written "nonmagical damage" to cover things like torches and falling but they didn't.

### Monks do not become magical creatures at level 6

Monks gain a class feature called *Ki-Empowered Strikes* that lets them treat their unarmed strikes as MFTPOOR.

> Starting at 6th level, your unarmed strikes count as magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage.

There's a few things worth pointing out here:

- This is essentially the same text that's in *Pact Weapon*.
- [Unarmed strikes are not weapons.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/666339794331414529)
- Ki is not magical for rule purposes.
  ([1](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/702205711011328000), [2](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/530137985954492416), [3](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/702227753706266624))
- Even if Ki were magical, it would be a huge stretch to say the Monk's entire body becomes magical.

That third point requires more explanation. Sage Advice addresses this in the question "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?". The answer is a bit long, so I'll quote the most relevant part:

> But our game makes a distinction between two types of magic:
>
> - the background magic that is part of the D&D multiverse’s physics and the physiology of many D&D creatures
> - the concentrated magical energy that is contained in a magic item or channeled to create a spell or other focused magical effect
>
> In D&D, the first type of magic is part of nature. It is no more dispellable than the wind. A monster like a dragon exists because of that magic-enhanced nature. The second type of magic is what the rules are concerned about. When a rule refers to something being magical, it’s referring to that second type. Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions about the feature
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical.

### It doesn't break anything

In terms of Rules As Fun, without any Unearthed Arcana material, a melee Warlock is generally less effective than an Eldritch Blast Warlock. The Eldritch Blast invocations are so powerful that it's almost difficult to justify using anything else. Anything that encourages diversity and lets players play how they want is a good thing. Let Blade Warlocks have their +1 weapons.

Answer (score 4):

### Fifth edition uses natural language, and these phrases are certainly different when viewed through that lens. A weapon that counts as magical for the purposes of overcoming resistances is not magical.

First let's just look over what the two phrases even are:

> a magical weapon

That would be, a weapon which *is* magical. If anything requires a magical (or non-magical) weapon, it will count as a magical weapon. Compare this to the following wording:

> a weapon that counts as magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to non-magical attacks and damage

This weapon *is* non-magical, **but** when it is being used to overcome resistances it *counts as magical* (A small thing that is unclear and matters more later is whether the weapon actually briefly *becomes* magical). If anything else requires a magical (or non-magical) weapon, it will count as a non-magical weapon.

---

This pretty clearly showcases that these are different things and for further evidence that these phrases mean different things: they both exist. Why would both phrases exist if they were equivalent; the books could simply have used one phrase every time, but instead both phrases occur regularly.

---

Now let's look at how this distinction ends up mattering throughout the game, first let's look at things which only work on non-magical weapons such as the [*animate objects*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) spell:

> [...] Choose up to ten **non-magical objects** within range that are not being worn or carried [...]

This spell would *not* work on magical weapons, but it *would* work on weapons that count as magical *only for overcoming resistances.*<sup>1</sup>

---

Now let's look at the [Warlock's Pact of the Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) which has a feature that only works on *magical weapons*:

> [...] You can transform one **magic weapon** into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon [...]

This would *not* work with a weapon which merely counts as magical for the purposes of overcoming resistances, but will work with any weapon that is *actually magical.*

---

There are ways to make a weapon flatly magical, for example the [shillelagh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) spell which states:

> [...] The weapon also becomes magical, if it isn't already [...]

This would work perfectly on either type of weapon here, especially since it includes the phrase "if it isn't already".

---

There are *also* ways to make a weapon that merely counts as magical for overcoming resistances such as the [Warlock's Pact of the Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) feature which states:

> [...] This weapon **counts as magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to non-magical attacks and damage** [...]

---

1 Note, this creates a problem/question: Do non-magical weapons of this sort actually *become* magical when overcoming relevant resistances or merely *count as magical*? Imagine that such a weapon is *animated* and attacks something resistant to non-magical damage: If the weapon actually *becomes* magical then it would no longer be a valid target of the *animate objects* spell, which is a bit of a problem. This is a separate question for sure.

Comment: "A small thing that is unclear... is whether the weapon actually briefly *becomes* magical".  My view on this is that "magic weapons" is shorthand for the a subset of all items like: `{+1 longsword, +1 shortsword, ..., Holy Avenger, ...etc}`.  WCMFTPOOR means that when when creatures refer to magic weapons in their resistances, they don't mean the above set but instead mean `{+1 longsword, ... Holy Avenger, ..., Pact Blade, WCMFTPOOR #2, WCMFTPOOR #3, etc}`.  The WCMFTPOORs aren't included in the "magic weapons" set but are included in the set of weapons that pierce resistance.

Comment: It is confusing though since these are two nonequal sets, but are refererred to by the same name in the places where they actually appear.  It's a property elsewhere (on the weapons) that says "oh, that set `MagicWeapons` that was referred to earlier?  It's actually not that set, it's `MagicWeapons ∪ WCMFTPOORs` in that one place.  (But it **is** the `MagicWeapons` set everywhere else it's mentioned...)"

Answer (score 2):

### WCMFTPOOR are not magic, they just count as magic for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage

In plain English, "counts as X" means to treat it as X.

Examples:

- I count this as a win.
- Did you count that one as a fair ball?
- Does a hamburger count as healthy if it has lettuce?

What's more, "counts as magical for the purpose of" clearly says there is only 1 situation where they "count as magical".

Answer (score -3):

Weapons considered magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance(s) do not give any magic bonus to attack or damage, whereas magical weapons do.

It seems I am again being chided a bit for providing an answer without an explainer and perhaps without enough substance. Although I am of the opinion my answer doesn't require an explainer, and substance may not always be relevant or even helpful, I'll add more information/explanation for context.

Conjured weapons should generally only be considered magical in the sense they are magic constructs, not that they are true "magic weapons". Unless the text of the spell/ability specifically states otherwise, any conjured weapon should be treated as a normal weapon of it's type, has no bonus to attack and/or damage and is not treated as a WCMFTPOOR.

Magic items that allow spells (or spell-like abilities) to be cast whereby the spells overcome resistances/reductions/etc are not themselves considered WCMFTPOOR - again, unless the text describing that magic item specifically states so.

Forgive me if this causes any offence, but from some of the answers I have read so far I can see a tendency to over-analyse and over-complicate interpretation of some rules. For the sake of enjoyment of the game Occam's Razor should be liberally applied to simplify any rule interpretation.

Final add (I hope) to my answer. In the responses to the OP's post he is directly asked to clarify a specific point, whereby his reply is "I am only asking if they (magic weapons vs WCMFTPOOR) are different" and that his supplying of examples is only support for the general question. The difference the OP is inquiring of is further clarified as being "a difference that is mechanically relevant" - which I took as meaning "relevant to the game mechanics". The only difference I can see between a magic weapon and a WCMFTPOOR that is "mechanically relevant" in the sense the OP suggests is the bonus to hit/damage of a magic weapon vs the WCMFTPOOR. Can anyone suggest another difference that is "mechanically relevant", or whether my interpretation of the OP's words are incorrect/too limited?

Comment: There are magical weapons with no attack/damage bonuses.

Comment: Which is a subset of the question the OP asked. From the perspective of answering the OP's question with regard the general difference between the 2 groups of weapons my answer is not incorrect, but thanks for your downvote whoever gave it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't really seem to resolve the actual problem given in the question. There is no confusion about other properties associated with magical vs WCMFTPOOR, merely whether the categories themselves are different/distinct.  It's possible there's some better title, but I'm not currently seeing it (open to ideas/edits, but I don't think it validates this answer).

Comment: The question asked in the OP is how magical weapons and WCMFTPOOR are different. How does my answer not address that? The question wasn't set as a problem to be resolved, only a difference to be pointed out.

Comment: Sorry, maybe terminology getting confused there. Problem in this case is not in the meaning of maths problem, but rather the problem the asker is facing and wants a solution for. The describe that problem in the question's body and then summarizes it in the title. So while the shorthand question is "Are they different?" the body, quite clearly by it's examples, gives what difference they are asking about, and this answer does not attempt to resolve that.

Comment: Okay, in that case there are numerous different answers that can all be considered "correct" while not being complete. There are many specific cases of difference, but only 1 general difference. That still doesn't make my answer not relevant to the OP, and no single reply here has resolved ALL the cases associated with the question. Is there an issue with the brevity of my answer? That it is relatively obvious?

Comment: This came up in the 'low-quality post' queue.  It is _not_ low-quality; it addresses the question and it is comprehensible.  On the other hand, it is simply incorrect - as Thomas Markov points out, there are magic weapons which _do not_ give a bonus to attack and damage.  The _staff of swarming insects_ comes immediately to mind.  The treatment for a quality answer that is incorrect is to downvote, not delete.

Comment: Now I'm not sure I'm following you, Leo. It's fairly clear (to me) which difference the question is about, and most of the other interpretations of the at-face question result in triviality or nonsense. As for brevity, it is not considered strictly a bad thing, rather it is often a positive, assuming it fully answers the question with justification (which may often involve providing sources). I'm not sure what "ALL the cases" you are thinking of (it might be illuminating to your understanding). What matters is resolving the case the question is interested in, which is not numerical bonuses.

Comment: This is definitely a legitimate answer, especially because I /JUST/ read someone saying the reason why Ki Strikes has helper text saying "WCMFTPOOR" is because people would argue that it gets +1 without that. People *are* making that mistake, and from what I can see no other answer addresses this confusion. Definitely a legitimate, comprehensible answer addressing a point of contention that exists IRL and not just within the realms of SE theorycrafting.

Comment: Kirt, I would argue the Staff of Swarming Insects is a magic item, not necessarily a magic weapon. It doesn't, to my knowledge have any magic bonus to attack or damage therefore doesn't meet the criteria for being in the latter category. Someone_Evil, when I wrote "ALL the cases" I was referencing answers incorporating examples such as conjured weapons, which may be considered magical weapons (in one sense) but have no magic bonus to attack and/or damage. For the sake of simplicity and clarity I kept my answer simple.